# angular/material md-slide-toggle cannot be re instantiated?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple model-driven Angular 2 form with two components:

1. An [Angular Material slide-toggle](https://material.angular.io/components/component/slide-toggle).
2. A single button, which when clicked calls `onReset(form: FormGroup)` on my Component.

See [this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QF25JB0lwYi1jXBGBogg). Code below:

**select-overview-example.html**

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
<md-slide-toggle formControlName="example">Example</md-slide-toggle>
<button md-raised-button (click)="onReset(form)">Reset</button>
</form>
```

**select-overview-example.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: './select-overview-example.html',
})
export class SelectOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  private form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  onReset(form: FormGroup) {
    this.createForm();
    return false;
  }


  private createForm() {
    let form = this.fb.group({
      example: true
    });

    this.form = form;
  }
}
```

The page loads fine (i.e. `constructor -> ngOnInit -> createForm`) and the `<md-slide-toggle>` is rendered.

Clicking the reset button uses the `FormBuilder` to (re)construct the form. I do this because I want specific values reset (rather than just *clearing* the entire form).

```
onReset(form: FormGroup) {
    this.createForm();
    return false;
  }
```

This works, but only when the [slide-toggle](https://material.angular.io/components/component/slide-toggle) is on. If toggled off, clicking the reset `<button>`, calling `onReset` and subsequently `createForm`, throws an exception (you'll have to look in your browser's developer console when using the [example Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QF25JB0lwYi1jXBGBogg)). Exception repeated below:

```
ERROR Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'example'
```

I added some debug logging to see what state the form's in, and the slide-toggle is instantiated:

```
private createForm() {
    if (this.form) {
        console.log(this.form.value.example);
    }
    let form = this.fb.group({
        example: true
    });
    this.form = form;
}
```

Prints `true` when the page loads, and `false` when clicking reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up 'solving' this using [FormGroup.getRawValue()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#getRawValue-anchor) immediately after the form's created using [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html). Essentially it allows me to create a snapshot / cache of the values when the form is created.

I use the [FormGroup.reset](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#reset-anchor) with my cached values.

Pseudo code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;
    defaultFormValues: any;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createForm();
    }

    createForm() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
           // Initialize your form fields here.
        });

        // Cache initialization values for reset.
        this.defaultFormValues = this.form.getRawValue();
    }

    resetForm() {
        // Use previously cached values to reset form.
        this.form.reset(this.defaultFormValues);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have update `createForm` function and its working fine.

```
private createForm() {
if (this.form) {
  console.log(this.form.value);
}
if(!this.form){
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    example: true
  });
}
this.form.controls['example'].setValue(true);
}
```

Comment: There are three things that make me think this is not right. 1) You're setting the value of example twice, to the same value, in the same function. 2) If I have a form with 20 input elements, I would end up with 40 lines of code. 3) It doesn't address the underlying issue of why everything works when the toggle is on, but not when it's off. That seems bugging to me?